# Vector of Signals/Slots in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

**First some background as to why I am trying to do this:** I have a class, say **MasterClass** which is a subclass of `QWidget`, that creates multiple new `QObject` derived class object, say **SlaveClass**, this happens dynamically during runtime. The new SlaveClass is moved to a new `QThread` by using `moveToThread` because it has to do long-running computations and I do not want my GUI to freeze. Since the SlaveClass is in a different thread, the proper way for me to invoke any method in the SlaveClass is by using Qt's Signal/Slot mechanism along with `Qt::QueuedConnection`. The SlaveClass has many *signals* and *slots* which I want to connect to my MasterClass. What I am trying to do is to create a `QVector` of *signals* and *slots* in my MasterClass so that I can add and remove from it dynamically and `connect` and `disconnect` these to my SlaveClass depending on if the SlaveClass is being created or destroyed.

To test out my theory I created a *MasterClass* and tried to create vectors of *signals* and *slots* inside it and tried connecting the *signals* to *slots* to see if it works:

**First try [doesn't work]:**

masterclass.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <functional>

Class MasterClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MasterClass(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MasterClass();

signals:
    void sig_test(int testID);
    QVector<std::function<void(int)>> vSig;

private slots:
    void slt_test(int testID);
    QVector<std::function<void(int)>> vSlt;
};
```

masterclass.cpp

```
#include "masterclass.h"

MasterClass::MasterClass(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    vSig << [this](int id) -> void{return this->sig_test(id); };
    vSig << [this](int id) -> void{return this->sig_test(id); };
    vSig << [this](int id) -> void{return this->sig_test(id); };

    vSlt << [this](int id) -> void{return this->slt_test(id); };
    vSlt << [this](int id) -> void{return this->slt_test(id); };
    vSlt << [this](int id) -> void{return this->slt_test(id); };

    connect(this, &MasterClass::vSig[0], this, &MasterClass::vSlt[0]);
    connect(this, &MasterClass::vSig[1], this, &MasterClass::vSlt[1]);
    connect(this, &MasterClass::vSig[2], this, &MasterClass::vSlt[2]);

    emit vSig[0](78);
    emit vSig[1](68);
    emit vSig[2](58);
}

void MasterClass::slt_test(int testID)
{
    qDebug() << "\n" << testID << "\n";
}
```

This gives 2 errors:

1. E0304: no instance of overloaded function "MasterClass::connect" matches the argument list
2. MSB4181: The "QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error.

The error no. 2 above is because I am declaring `QVector<std::function<void(int)>> vSig;` under `signals:` and `QVector<std::function<void(int)>> vSlt;` under `private slots:`. This error goes away as soon as I move the above two vectors under `private:`.

**Second Try [works, but only kind of]:**

masterclass.h

```
.
.
.

signals:
    void sig_test(int testID);

private slots:
    void slt_test(int testID);

private:
    QVector<std::function<void(int)>> vSig;
    QVector<std::function<void(int)>> vSlt;
};
```

masterclass.cpp

```
.
.
.
    vSig << [this](int id) -> void{return this->sig_test(id); };
    vSig << [this](int id) -> void{return this->sig_test(id + 1); }; // Notice change in argument
    vSig << [this](int id) -> void{return this->sig_test(id + 2); }; // Notice change in argument

    vSlt << [this](int id) -> void{return this->slt_test(id); };
    vSlt << [this](int id) -> void{return this->slt_test(id + 10); }; // Notice change in argument
    vSlt << [this](int id) -> void{return this->slt_test(id + 20); }; // Notice change in argument

    connect(this, &MasterClass::sig_test, this, &MasterClass::slt_test);

    emit vSig[0](78);
    emit vSig[1](68);
    emit vSig[2](58);
}

void MasterClass::slt_test(int testID)
{
    qDebug() << "\n" << testID << "\n";
}
```

This works and prints:
78
69
60

There are two things to note here:

1. If I remove the `connect(this, &MasterClass::sig_test, this, &MasterClass::slt_test);` line, it prints nothing.
2. Notice the change in the arguments when creating the `vSig` and `vSlt` vectors. From the output, I can see that the correct `vSig` is being called as it adds 1 to the argument of the second `vSig` function and adds 2 to the argument of the third `vSig` function. However, it doesn't add 10 to the argument of the second `vSlt` function or 20 to the argument of the third `vSlt` function, this makes me wonder if it is calling the correct `vSlt` function or is it just calling `slt_test()` function?

Is there any way I can improve this?

When creating `SlaveClass` objects dynamically, I would have to do something like this to connect to it's slots `connect(MasterClassPointer, &MasterClass::vSig[id], SlaveClassPointer, &SlaveClass::slotName);`. Is it possible?

P.S. I know I can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` function but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: I think it's clearly not calling your `vSlt` slots. Why would it? You're never connecting anything to those slots.

Comment: Thanks, I understand and I think the same but then why is it connecting `vSig` signals to `slt_test` slot? I never made this connection either. Only `sig_test` is connected to `slt_test`

Comment: `vSig` is just a vector of functions. And those functions simply call `sig_test`. Since `sig_test` is connected to `slt_test`, calling `vSig` arrives at `slt_test`.

Comment: @JarMan Thanks, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a vector of slots (a lambda function can be a slot), but you can't really have a vector of signals. However, you can have your signal connected to something that dispatches to the correct slot based on ID:

```
// MasterClass.h
class MasterClass : public QObject {
// ... class stuff ...

signals:
  void masterSignal(int id);

private:
std::unordered_map<int, SlaveClass*> m_slaveMap;

}

// MasterClass.cpp ...
connect(this, &MasterClass::masterSignal, slavePtr,
  [](int id) { m_slaveMap[id]->slot(); });
```

The other option is to just filter out calls with the wrong ID on the slave slot:

```
int slaveID = /*something*/
connect(masterPtr, &MasterClass::masterSignal, slavePtr,
  [myID = slaveID, slavePtr] (int id) { if (myID == id) slavePtr->slot(); });
```

Comment: Thanks! Filtering out is not a good idea as it will create copies of data being sent to the slots since the slots are in different threads. I will try the first method of using a slavemap.